# Can we connect Rest Assured framework with Splunk

Tags: java, api, rest-assured, splunk, jira-rest-java-api

I am using Rest assured framework with a mix  of Spring libraries. Recently i did JIRA integration to send results of my test case to update in JIRA. Now to be more precise in order to check failures logs i want to read the logs from Splunk using some API that will help me integrate my framework with Splunk same as JIRA.
Is there any API using which i can connect directly to Splunk same as we have one for JIRA Integration. Your info is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you were looking for this? [Table of endpoints](https://dev.splunk.com/observability/docs/apibasics/api_list#Table-of-endpoints)

good coding! ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: thanks let me check on this